# How do I loop through Javascript array objects with forEach to create an element?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to  loop through an array object with JavaScript forEach, then the function should create an OPTION element, set its value to the item's id, set its text to the item's name, and then add the OPTION to the SELECT element?

I've tried returning each item as template literals

```
const currencies = [{
        id: 'USD', name: 'US Dollars'
      },     {    
        id: 'UGX', name: 'Ugandan Shillings'
      },     {
        id: 'KES', name: 'Kenyan Shillings'
      },     {
        id: 'GHS', name: 'Ghanian Cedi'
      },     {
        id: 'ZAR', name: 'South African Rand'
      }];

currencies.forEach(function(currency){    
  str = `<option value="${id}"></option>`   
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
const currencies = [{
  id: 'USD',
  name: 'US Dollars'
}, {
  id: 'UGX',
  name: 'Ugandan Shillings'
}, {
  id: 'KES',
  name: 'Kenyan Shillings'
}, {
  id: 'GHS',
  name: 'Ghanian Cedi'
}, {
  id: 'ZAR',
  name: 'South African Rand'
}];

const selectEl = document.querySelector('#selectEl');
currencies.forEach(function(currency) {
  const option = document.createElement('option');
  option.setAttribute('value', currency.id);
  option.text = currency.name;
  selectEl.appendChild(option);
})
```

```html
<select id="selectEl">
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery

```js
const currencies = [{ id: 'USD', name: 'US Dollars' }, {
id: 'UGX', name: 'Ugandan Shillings' }, { id: 'KES', name: 'Kenyan Shillings' }, { id: 'GHS', name: 'Ghanian Cedi' }, { id: 'ZAR', name: 'South African Rand' }];

currencies.forEach(function(currency){
  $('#list').append(`<option value="${currency.id}">${currency.name}</option>`)
})
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<select id="list"></select>
```

With pure JS

```js
const currencies = [{ id: 'USD', name: 'US Dollars' }, {
id: 'UGX', name: 'Ugandan Shillings' }, { id: 'KES', name: 'Kenyan Shillings' }, { id: 'GHS', name: 'Ghanian Cedi' }, { id: 'ZAR', name: 'South African Rand' }];

currencies.forEach(function(currency){
  var el = document.getElementById('list');
  var elChild = document.createElement('option');

  // Give the new div some content
  elChild.innerHTML = currency.name;
  elChild.id = currency.id

  // Jug it into the parent element
  el.appendChild(elChild);
})
```

```html
<select id="list"></select>
```

Comment: How do I do this without jQuery?

Comment: I have added a snippet with pure JS.

Comment: You need to be setting value, not id

Comment: The value is set by innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

```js
const currencies = [{ id: 'USD', name: 'US Dollars' }, { id: 'UGX', name: 'Ugandan Shillings' }, { id: 'KES', name: 'Kenyan Shillings' }, { id: 'GHS', name: 'Ghanian Cedi' }, { id: 'ZAR', name: 'South African Rand' }];

$('select').append(currencies.map(c => $(`<option value="${c.id}">${c.name}</option>`)));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`Template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (that are enclosed with back-tick (` `)) which allows embedded expressions:

```js
const currencies = [{ id: 'USD', name: 'US Dollars' }, {
id: 'UGX', name: 'Ugandan Shillings' }, { id: 'KES', name: 'Kenyan Shillings' }, { id: 'GHS', name: 'Ghanian Cedi' }, { id: 'ZAR', name: 'South African Rand' }];
var str = '';
currencies.forEach(function(currency){
  str += `<option value=${currency.id}>${currency.name}</option>`;
});

document.getElementById('mySelect').innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<select id="mySelect"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have one approach thay uses [Array::map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array::join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
const currencies = [
  {id: 'USD', name: 'US Dollars'},
  {id: 'UGX', name: 'Ugandan Shillings'},
  {id: 'KES', name: 'Kenyan Shillings'},
  {id: 'GHS', name: 'Ghanian Cedi'},
  {id: 'ZAR', name: 'South African Rand'}
];

let sel = document.getElementById("mySelect");

sel.innerHTML = currencies.map(
  ({id, name}) => `<option value=${id}>${name}</option>`
).join("");
```

```html
<select id="mySelect"></select>
```